# Avoid fetching deleted NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Using `NSFetchRequest`, is it possible to avoid fetching a `NSManagedObject` that *has been* or *will be* deleted?

I know it's possible to check `-isDeleted` or if `-managedObjectContext` returns nil, but is there a way to do this in the database layer?

Comment: Try saving the context before fetching.

Comment: I'd rather call `-processPendingChanges`, and it's not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if the object is truly deleted it will not show up at the database layer. What are the symptoms of the problem presenting as?

Comment: Maybe the phrase "database layer" was misleading. I want to know if it's possible to avoid fetching objects that will be removed from the store with the next save operation.

Comment: Still not sure why you might want to do that. If your application is multithreaded, it's possible that any object might get deleted (and thus turn into a fault). If you are using one `NSManagedObjectContext` then as Costique says, saving it first will at least ensure that the pending deletes get pushed down to the `NSPersistentObjectStoreCoordinator`.Pending deletes would only be known to the individual `NSManagedObjectContext` anyway, not to peer ones hanging off the same persistent store. Can you elaborate on exactly what problem is causing you to want the fetch to work this way?

Comment: I'm syncing with a web service, inserting and deleting objects at arbitrary times. The UI is observing changes to the context and creates a fetch request whenever a particular change occurs. However, this request is also returning the objects to be deleted with the next save and I'd rather filter them out in the request than after fetching.