# NSFetchedResultsController still brings back the NSManagedObject, which has been deleted

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have checked several related issue like [How can I tell whether an `NSManagedObject` has been deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340445/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-nsmanagedobject-has-been-deleted), [Avoid fetching deleted NSManagedObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415071/avoid-fetching-deleted-nsmanagedobjects).

But I did using `deleteCacheWithName` and `deleteObject:` and `save`, and have check the object has been deleted too. Every time I remove App from the background. And start it all over, the deleted data `NSManagedObject` come back again.

This is how I delete `NSManagedObject`.

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"MyLists"];
[_fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext deleteObject:list];
NSError *error;
if ([_fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
  NIDPRINT(@"managedObjectContext Save Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
NIDPRINT(@"Check hasManagedObjectBeenDeleted: %@", [self hasManagedObjectBeenDeleted:list] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

And this is how I initial `NSFetchedResultsController`

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyList"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"listID" ascending:YES] ];
NSString *userName = [[ICAccountManager sharedManager] getUsername];
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username==\"%@\"", userName];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format];

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"count"];
fetchRequest.shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects = YES;
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"lists"];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
[_fetchedResultsController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performFetch:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES modes:@[ NSRunLoopCommonModes ]];
```

Is there any way I can check if I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

After you delete something, you should add:

```
NSError *error;
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

That will commit the action.